# why a count parameter work in windows but not working in linux

Tags: php, laravel

i have a function in laravel like this:

```
    public function Add(BirthValidate $request){
        $mobile=$request->mobile;
        $name=$request->name;
        Smsirlaravel::addToCustomerClub('mr',$name,'birthday',$mobile);
}
```

this is work very well in my xammp in windows but its not working in cpanel linux host, and showing this error:

```
local.ERROR: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable at /home/../vendor/ipecompany/smsirlaravel/src/Smsirlaravel.php:23)
```

Comment: Most likely, you are running two different PHP versions. On PHP 7.2, that error is thrown when you pass null as a parameter to count.

Comment: That's possibly happening because the PHP version are different on both enviroments. Check my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978059/phpdoc-php-warning-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-imple/57978308#57978308)

Comment: your xampp runs on php 5.x and in php 7.2+ its error

Comment: i know but i think this problem is related to my encoding because i this is a part of my logs:
(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response), '\\xD8\\xA7\\xD9\\x81\\xD8\\xB2\\xD9\\x88\\xD8\\xAF\\xD9\\x86 sd...', Array)

Comment: You need to extract and provide a [mcve]. Chances are that you will find the reason yourself doing that.